# fpm python uwsgi service

Tags: python, virtualenv, deb

I'm working on distributing a python package that uses uwsgi and falcon to run an API.

To build it as a deb package I am using `fpm`. After some tinkering I have managed to get my package to include everything I need for my virtualenv, however now I am running into the problem that my service files aren't installing properly and I can't start the service with `systemctl`

I build the package using:
`fpm -s virtualenv -t deb --prefix /opt/venvs/{project_name} --version {$VERS} --name {project_name} path/to/setup.py path/to/requirements.txt`

Inside my package I have `systemd/{service_name}.service`, however the service files aren't in my package when I check the contents with `dpkg -c {service_name}.deb | grep service`

How can I get fpm to build the deb package with the service files correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that it's possible to add an option `--deb-systemd FILEPATH` which points to which file should be put in systemd for the service and solved my issue.